# Morris chart not working (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, morris.js

I am working on a little interface built around AngularJS. I have an `index.html` file and I built a route to a `base.html` file (using ng-view) which contains several elements including a Morris chart.
However, when I launch my `index.html` everything from the `base.html` is displayed... except the chart. And I have the following error in the console :
`Error: Graph container element not found`

So I tried, to move my scripts `morris.js` (and 2 others) to the `base.html` juste after my element (that will contain the chart) is created but it doesn't work neither.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div ng-app="pistApp" ng-controller="MainController" id="wrapper">
    <div ng-view id="page-wrapper">

    </div>
</div>
```

`base.html`

```
<!-- other elements who works but I simplify -->
<div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
```

Comment: inspect element and look network tab. is morris.js getting 200 OK response or not?

Comment: Yes, when morris.js is in index.html but when i put it in base.html, i don't see it in the network tab

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks to [Angularjs does not load scripts within ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view)

I just had to include jQuery before angular script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Include in your project-'raphael/raphael.js','morris.js/morris.js', 'angular-morris-chart/src/angular-morris-chart.js','morris.js/morris.css'
```

These files will be in your bower_components after the bower install angular-morris-chart.

Try examples in https://angular-morris-chart.stpa.co/

it will work.