# How to run script when MVC view is loaded in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am passing a model object to MVC view which uses angularjs controller. In the script, I am accessing the model object and saving the model values to a variable. When the view is loaded, it does not run the script.
how can I load the AppSettings variable?

Thank you!

```
<script>
 var AppSettings = (function (o) {
    return o;
 })(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.AppSettings)));

 alert("app settings = " + AppSettings);
</script>

<form name="payment" ng-submit="send()" ng-controller="PaymentCtrl">
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it the angular/REST way, expose the app settings in a REST service returning JSON, and using $http in the controller to load the settings?

Comment: @JB Nizet Why make an extra request to the server when you don't have to?  I'd prefer the OP method to making an extra call.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish with the settings here...  Is this supposed to be some global function you can use to get a setting?

Comment: To keep the application clean: a HTML template is supposed to contain a HTML template, not data. And BTW, it's loaded only once and cached.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs does not load scripts within ng-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view)

Comment: I am trying to load the app settings from web.config in MVC controller method and passing them to MVC view. But the intention is to use them in angularjs service so I need the settings in a global variable.

Comment: Ideally, I need the settings to be available when the application is launched so that they will be available across the application. I am not sure how to do that. But for now, I am trying to pass them as model object to a view to access them from that point on. Thanks.

Comment: If you need it everywhere, and from the start of the application, why do you write it in a specific view, and not in the main HTML page (index.html)?

Comment: Ok. I could do that. But what should I do to run the script when view is loaded? Thanks!

Comment: Does angularjs ignore the script?

Comment: I see that it requires a reference to jquery to run the script as suggested in your link. Thanks!