# Why are scripts tags not displayed in the inpector of browser if and when you put them inside div which has ng-view in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular routing. And my question is that, if I include Scripts tags in the div which has ng-view, the script tags are not displayed in the browser inspector. But, still everything works perfectly fine.

***Now I am sure that it is a bad practice to include scripts inside ng-view. But still wanted to understand as to why this happens.***

P.S. : The execution of scripts works fine. Its just that the browser Inspector does not show the scripts. Although the scripts are still there if I do a view source.

***HTML***

```
<html ng-app="imgPrcApp">
<head>
    <title>Image Processing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/imgPrc.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***JS***

```
var imgPrcApp = angular.module('imgPrcApp', ['ngRoute']);

imgPrcApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

/**** Routing of HTML Templates ****/
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/pages/qc.html',
        controller: 'QCController'
    })
    .when('/editor', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/pages/editor.html',
        controller: 'editorController'
    });
}])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Mitali. Can you show your code please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs does not load scripts within ng-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view)

Comment: @WeNeigh: The link above does not explain my question. Have added a P.S. to exactly tell the difference.

Comment: @Vineet : Added a part of code snippet above. Now there are no functional issues here. But its just the browser inspector does not show the <script> tag that I have used while if I do a view source, the <script> tag is very much there. Also, functionally everything works fine.

Comment: @MitaliDas Is there any code which effects script tags ?