# AngularJS ui view don't get functionality of external JavaScript file that loaded with main view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

when the index page load with ui-view,the injected view works fine But when i change the state and the new view injected it's not get the functionality that define in app/app.js & all.js which loaded initially with the main view.Although the injected ui view gets the css file but not js file which loaded earlier with the main index.html. 
 here is the index.html and config.js 
[image]

here navbar.html and controller
[image]

Comment: No idea what *"not getting the javascript file"* means. Provide better detailed problem description

Comment: @charlietfl i have tried to explain clearly to you.. Now u can see. If anything else u need just cmnt.

Comment: Please add information from the console, which error is throwing you?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval no error is throwing. Due to not getting the all.js and app.js  that loaded with index.html. the ui-view not performing some functionality that  defined on that all.js & app.js script. Though the network shows those two js file already loaded. but ui-view don't get them. 
it's similar to this problem  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view

Comment: Your urlRouterProvider redirect to `/index` but i didn't see any state like that.

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval /index state is define below but i didn't attach that on screen shot. Besides it's not necessary because it's not going to /index , the desire ui-view is injected, problem is some of the functionality of that view not working that is define of all.js & app.js.

Comment: uhm sound stupid, but you tried to put your all.js and app.js after jquery and angular dependency's? they are declared before, if them use a angular o jquery component they wont load properly.

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval may be ur right and already i have tried that before posting the question , it didn't work.