# Checkout.com with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkout, ng-view

I am wotking on an Angularjs app and trying to integrate with [Checkout.com](http://docs.checkout.com/)

I am using data-attributes integration method :

**checkout.html**

```
<form method="POST">
<script id="cko_script_tag" src="https://cdn.checkout.com/js/checkout.js"
    data-public-key="pk_ea61f128-e700-4598-88c9-e67852148c54"
    data-payment-token="pay_tok_88E83A65-C7E8-4D47-B1E0-75883E2F6C11"
    data-customer-email="customer@email.com"
    data-value="100"
    data-currency="GBP"
    data-debug-mode="true">
</script>
```

It working great when using on index.html page but when I am using it in any view it show nothing!!

I used both ui-router and ngRoute modules but with no hope

I also try to compile this html via `$compile` but it doesn't work too.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>

    <a href="#/packages">go to pay</a>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

**app.js**

```
  $routeProvider
.when('/packages',{
  templateUrl:'templates/packages.html',
  controller:'packages'
})
.when('/checkout',{
  templateUrl:'templates/checkout.html',
  controller:'checkout'
})
```

any help please!!

Comment: The view where it is not working, is there your angular app initialized?

Comment: it's not working on any view on my angular module, it only works on index.html outside `ng-view` directive

Comment: Checkout.com is not angular dependant right? Can I have more html code of your form?

Comment: checked my edited question

Comment: Do you have jQuery?

Comment: is the correct view getting loaded on the given `url`? according to your route configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that within `ng-view` scripts are not evaluated. Unless you have jQuery loaded before angularJs that will make the job with its `html()` method. Otherwise just `innerHTML` will be used (by angular jQlite) and your script is not launched.

For further information, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220411/5566936