# emojionearea pickup icon is not displaying with ngRoute angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I'm trying to implement http://mervick.github.io/emojionearea/ using ngRoute of `angularjs` without success.

If I remove the ngRoute routing pages it works without any errors, but if `index.html` has the source of `Emoticons.html`.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
      <title>Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>

      <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color: #006699;
        }

      </style>

</head>
    <body>

      <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="HomeController">

        <div class="container" style="color: #FFFFFF">

            <h2> Home</h2>

            <ul class="nav">

                <li> <a href="#/Emoticons" style="color: #FFFFFF"> Emoticons</a> </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

#### Emoticons.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Emojione-area</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <textarea id="example1"> 
      Smile  ghost  umbrella ☔ dephin .
    </textarea>

    <div>
                <a href="#/home" style="color: #FFFFFF"> Home</a>
        </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example1").emojioneArea({
      autoHideFilters: true,
      pickerPosition: "bottom",
      tonesStyle: "radio"
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```
'use strict';

var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working
    //https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/Emoticons', {
            templateUrl: 'Emoticons.html',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

});
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HoBx5HCTB5W8OkO37Wwm that is not working.

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hCTy20oJHbAFIhIDlj5l working without ngRoute.

Thank you so much!
Ariel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a problem of placing the scripts. As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view), you should include jquery before angular so the js in template got evaluated. You also need to put emojionarea script in the index:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
      <title>Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>

        <script src="main.js"></script>

      <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color: #006699;
        }

      </style>

</head>
    <body>

      <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Check my fork of your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/myZY8d2Rx4Oz0l67WDYf