# How to execute javascript/html using angular scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, interpolation

Want to submit form dynamically though scope variable.But it is not working. Even, simple example as below that alert is also not executing.

```
$scope.sctext = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div>text<script type="javascript">alert('working'); other scripts</script></div>');
```

Html:

```
  <div>{{sctext}}</div>
```

Is it possible to execute javascript & html like above?

Comment: Its for - payment gateway integration where dynaimically created form which is going to submit through script only. so, wanted to pass that script to html. finally solve by - directive - link - element.append which place that script and solved.

Comment: there was no point to downvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs does not load scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved by - directive - link (element) { element.append(script) }